# Expanding the summary table in r

Tags: r, statistics

Good day,

I've got a table with 15000 rows of data with 5 variable columns. I'm using the summary function in R and I get the following output:

[image]

Which is fine, however, I was wondering if there was any way to either expand this to include the standard deviation and the 0.025 and 0.975 quantiles so the final table would appear as follows,

[image]

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all functions in R are open source, you can edit them to do whatever you want. Short of that, the simplest solution is to find another descriptive statistics function in an R package that is closer to what you want. There are many options, but one that comes very close to what you want is `numSummary()` in the `RcmdrMisc` package:

```
library(RcmdrMisc)
data(iris)
options(digits=4)
numSummary(iris[, 1:4], statistics=c("mean", "sd", "quantiles"), 
      quantiles=c(.025, .5, .975))
#               mean     sd  2.5%  50% 97.5%   n
# Sepal.Length 5.843 0.8281 4.473 5.80 7.700 150
# Sepal.Width  3.057 0.4359 2.272 3.00 3.928 150
# Petal.Length 3.758 1.7653 1.272 4.35 6.455 150
# Petal.Width  1.199 0.7622 0.100 1.30 2.400 150
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked like a charm using the RcmdrMisc package,

[image]

Thank you dcarlson